# Pentaho 5.0.1-stable Marketplace don't show any item

Tags: pentaho

I have install pentaho 5.0.1-stable on my server.
and access it via local ip address port 8080 from the client.
Everything works fine accept the marketplace menu.

When i have opened marketplace, there is no item show and the javascript console log show error as following

```
[info] WD: Response: null 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null marketplace.js:113
impl.processPluginListResponse marketplace.js:113
fire jquery.js:1047
self.fireWith jquery.js:1165
done jquery.js:7400
callback jquery.js:8181
```

When i hit refresh button, it still error the same.

biserver in my localhost do work fine...

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Please help,

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the server behind a firewall ? 
the marketplace is not able to function in Pentaho 5.0.1 if you're using a firewall.

That has been fixed on 5.2 (or 5.1, can't remember).

Comment: Ok, i will try and tell you the result soon!

Comment: Turn out it was my VM that has the wrong DNS.
But turn off firewall is also worth to try!